# transferring from using javac to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, javac

I'm using Javac to compile my program and I use cmd to excute the following .bat file:

```
@set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101
@set THIS_DIR=C:\Users\Peter\workspace\HYSYSTry\src
@set JINTEGRA_RELEASE=C:\Users\Peter\jintegra6402\com6402


@set CLASSPATH=%THIS_DIR%;%JINTEGRA_RELEASE%\lib\jintegra.jar
@set PATH=%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\system32;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JINTEGRA_RELEASE%\bin
```

Could you help me on how to write the paths right on Eclipse?
I tried File>properties>Linked Resources and Run configurations>ClassPath ... but nothing seems to work... When I use cmd and javac, it works perfectly fine but never on Eclipse

Comment: Copy the jars you need to your project, and right-click on each of them to add them to your build path.  Consider learning Maven.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried that but the problem still exists.. Could you please tell me why Maven would be helpful?

Comment: Then you need to add more detail about why it doesn't work.  Maven handle dependencies, this mean the jars that your program need to run but at your current level it may be too hard.

Comment: Thank you very much, I guess it just needed a restart, your suggestion solved the problem :) Thank you again